# How to use theme 1.9 into Magento version 2.x

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, theme

What will happen if i imported theme 1.9 into Magento version 2.x
and is there a way or procedures to migrate theme 1.x to 2.x
or is it difficult to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult it's impossible.

Comment: Adding to what @nuovecode stated - So much changed with Magento 2. Thus the new number as well. It would serve you best to get a Magento 2 theme. You would be spinning your wheels trying to get a theme that was built for M1 to fit M2.

Comment: so, what it is the solution if there is a theme on evanto for version 1.9 and the client liked it and needed to apply it on Magento 2 ?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a solution, M1 and M2 are two different platforms. You should redo the theme.